# Python: Importing a module practically next to my main file isn't working

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import, importerror

I'm using Pycharm and my file structure currently looks like this:

```
\Machine Problem 1
    MP1_Core.py
    MP1_Miscellaneous.py
    MP1_Guest.py
    MP1_Staff.py
```

The interior of MP1_Core.py looks like this:

```
import MP1_Miscellaneous

def main():
    ...

main()
```

MP1_Miscellaneous is highlighted with a pop-up 
"No module named MP1_Miscellaneous"

On running, it yields this error

```
File "C:/Users/User-Pc/PycharmProjects/Computer Science Works/Machine Problem 1/MP1_Core.py", line 1, in <module>
    import MP1_Miscellaneous.py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MP1_Miscellaneous.py'; 'MP1_Miscellaneous' is not a package
```

To clarify, in my eyes, the files are practically right next to each other and I have no idea why it isn't importing. Thanks in advance

Comment: Typo? `import MP1_Miscellaneous.py` != `import MP1_Miscellaneous`

Comment: As far as I know, they're the same. I could be wrong though.

Comment: I would try two things: 1) add an empty `__init__.py` file to your main directory `Machine Problem 1`; 2) rename the main directory so that its name doesn't contain spaces, perhaps...? No idea if this could be an issue.

Comment: @o0V0o They're not the same, that's what I was trying to say. Use the one without the file extension.

Comment: Try to right-click on `Machine Problem 1` and call `Mark As - Sources Root`